# Can a Pact of the Blade warlock turn a cursed magic weapon into your pact weapon to bypass the curse?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, curses

I would like to rid myself of a cursed weapon (whose curse includes the traditional "you may not unequip this weapon" aspect), but don't have access to *Remove Curse*. Can I turn the cursed weapon into my pact weapon, dismiss the item, and then make a new weapon my pact weapon to get rid of the cursed weapon without *Remove Curse*?

Comment: What is the specific weapon? Some have special rules attached to them.

Comment: I think its something home-brewed, sword of dim light.

Comment: @Tom: Your question would probably be improved if you included the exact details on the weapon, so answerers can determine whether their solutions would actually work in your case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

The simple answer to this is that if the rules don't specifically state that bonding/dismissing a pact weapon can break curses then it does not break curses.  Besides, if curses could easily be removed by meta gaming like this then they would lose all meaning.  Curses are supposed to have impact.

When the PHB describes dismissing a magic item that has been transformed into your pact weapon, it says:

> You can dismiss the weapon, shunting it into an extradimensional space, and **it appears whenever you create your pact weapon thereafter.**

If you bond the weapon as your pact weapon then it ***is*** your pact weapon.  There is nothing here that could break a curse.

If you bond to a different weapon or you perform a ritual to remove your bond to the cursed weapon then

> The weapon appears at your feet if it is in the extradimensional space when the bond breaks.

So not only do the rules say nothing about breaking curses, they specifically state that the weapon always returns to you.  Again, nothing here that could break a curse.

Answer (score 12):

### No

Or more accurately: no better than you could through any other means. If a cursed weapon you're using doesn't have any rules that say otherwise, you may be free to call and dismiss it as suggested, but you could also just set it on the ground and walk away from it.

Much more likely, you're dealing with a cursed weapon that has some rules that prevent you from getting rid of it. For example, the [Berserker Axe](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/berserker-axe) has the following:

> **Curse.** This axe is cursed, and becoming attuned to it extends the curse to you. As long as you remain cursed, you are unwilling to part with the axe, keeping it within reach at all times. You also have disadvantage on attack rolls with weapons other than this one, unless no foe is within 60 feet of you that you can see or hear.

Being "unwilling to part with the axe" and needing to "keep [...] it within reach at all times" would prevent one from dismissing the axe into extradimensional space using your Pact of the Blade feature, although it would encourage you to bond with it as your pact weapon, in order to return it to you immediately, were it ever forcibly taken from you. However, no part of the Pact of the Blade feature explicitly allows the feature to break curses, so no combination of effects that the feature grants can rid you of the cursed weapon. You'll need to find a different way.

Comment: I'd argue that making an item your Pact Weapon would keep it within reach at all times, since you can just conjure it into your hand with a moment's thought.

Comment: @nick012000 I'd agree - in fact, the curse would make you *more* likely to want to make it your Pact Weapon, because then even if it did somehow get beyond your reach, you could simply resummon it.

Comment: This is key: "you are unwilling to part with the axe". I wonder if the OP *player* disagrees with such sentiment. By definition, their PC *does not*. (Assuming the curse on their weapon works like this.)

Comment: @nick012000 The "unwilling to part with" wording makes it a bit debatable but I'm inclined to agree with you based on what the intention seems to be. (I'd rule as DM they could make the axe their pact weapon.) But more to the point of the question, the PC couldn't then bond to another weapon and somehow have broken the curse. They'd still want to keep the axe around at all times, and moreover probably wouldn't *want* to bond with any other weapon. Plus the disadvantage with other weapons would still apply.

Comment: i have not been informed that i like this weapon very much, think of it like Tim Allens beard in The Santa Clause.